# Samba Share no working

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

I have followed the answer on this post [Simple Samba Share - NO PASSWORD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781963/simple-samba-share-no-password)

So my server shows up under network,I can connect and view the list of shares however I cannot open any of my shares. Windows times out and says "is not accessible, you might not have permission.....etc"

I think I setup permissions correctly, unless I have missed something.

I have chmod'ed the folder that te share links to.
I have chown'ed the folder to nobody.nogroup.

```
[global]
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        server role = standalone server
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[WEB]
        path = /var/www/html
        read only = No
        create mask = 0777
        guest ok = Yes
```