# Beautiful Samba Folder sharing in Gnome / Nautilus don't work

Tags: networking, gnome, nautilus, samba, shared-folders

[image]

Sharing a Samba network folder in Ubuntu 16.04 seems to be as simple as users always wanted it to be, but it does not work this way.

The share shows up on other PCs – Linux and Windows based – but it's just not possible to connect as anonymous or guest user.

Note: The first time I changed Folder Sharing options, it automatically set file and folder permission to read for others (774). So this is sufficient, right?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's more complicated than that.  The answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781963/simple-samba-share-no-password?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows how to set it up the way you want.